# Wordpress query, exclude latest post from a category

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

Is it possible to get posts from all categories but exlude only one latest post from specific categories.
Something like: get posts from all categories, but exclude latest post from category 2,4 and 5.
PS. I'm looking for wordpress query (not mysql), for example somethng like

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=10'); ?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=10&offset=1'); ?>
```

Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, I would suggest something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT id FROM posts WHERE category IN (2,4,5) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but im looking for wordpress query, something like  `<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=10'); ?>`.